# Autofac Lazy Loading

Tags: lazy-loading, autofac

I am using following in my ASP.Net MVC project with .Net Framwork 4.5.2. : Autofac 4, Autofac MVC5, Autofac MVC WebAPI2.

I have successfully integrated Autofac. However, I want to know if i Have to do something extra like `Lazy<T>` and `Func<T>` stuff or Autofac implicitly loads the dependencies lazily? Please confirm.

Comment: You'll need to show some code and an actual problem to get help. The docs for Autofac explain `Lazy<T>` resolution (http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#delayed-instantiation-lazy-b).

Comment: Maybe look at the documentation?

Comment: Thanks Ian... solves my problem!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question, if Autofac implicitly loads the dependencies lazily, is NO. You simply register your services/components with the container and Autofac will resolve it as a `Lazy<T>` or `Owned<T>` or `Func<Owned<T>>`.

Also, the decision whether you should inject a service dependency as `Lazy`, would rather depend on how you intend to use that particular service. Autofac just resolves the dependencies as you ask it to, there is nothing like implicit resolution strategy.

I hope that helps. If you have any further question, I'll be more than happy to answer.